# Align view in the center of another view

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout:

[image]

Which i have create with this code:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:id="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|end"
    android:background="#ff4fc3f7" />
<LinearLayout
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:text="Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BusinessNameTextView"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Address_Text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:typeface="normal" />
<TextView
    android:text="Address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BusinessAddressTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessNameTextView"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Address_Text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:typeface="normal" />
<TextView
    android:text="Website"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/BusinessWebsiteTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessAddressTextView"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Address_Text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:text="5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/CommentsCountTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/Counter_Default_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:typeface="normal" />
<TextView
    android:text="overall thanks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CommentsCountTextView"
    android:id="@+id/CommentsTextTextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/SubCounter_Text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/subtitle_color"
    android:typeface="normal" />
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CommentsTextTextView"
    android:id="@+id/StaffTeamListView" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyMessagesListTextView"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

The problem is that i want the 3 textview to be in the vertical center of the imageview on the left. but i dont know how to do that, i have try with relative layout and also wrapping those textview on a linearlayout

but the problem is always the same, how i can set the linearlayout to center the content according to the image? if i can do this without linearlayout i would prefer it, keep in mind also that i want to display a small image (icon) on the left of every textview.

One solution that i have in mind is if i put the imageview and the linearlayout with the textviews into another linearlayout and allign then center vertical but is this the best solution?

Comment: You mean side by side?

Comment: i want the center of the imageview to be equal with the center of the 3 textviews together

Comment: You can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51068096/9121129) using constraint layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some "pseudo" code:

```
linearlayout orientation=horizontal, width=wrap_content
      imageview

      linearlayout orientation=vertial, width=0dp, weight=1
          textview1
          textview2
          textview 3
```

A weight of 1 will give the textviews' parent the remaining space.

Comment: and what about the extra imageview i said that i want to put on the left of every textview?

Comment: Check my edit. I wasn't sure if I got what you were asking

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to have the image and the 3 texts in a RelativeLayout wrapped.

The height of the relative layout is given by the wrapped content, while inside of it the items are centered vertically, meaning that either the image or the 3 lines of text could vary in height and the other one will be centered.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right|end"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="#ff4fc3f7" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <TextView
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/BusinessNameTextView"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        <TextView
                android:text="Address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/BusinessAddressTextView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessNameTextView"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:typeface="normal" />
        <TextView
                android:text="Website"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/BusinessWebsiteTextView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessAddressTextView"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks,is it lighter to have a relative layout with inside another relative layout and the linearlayout or better have a relative layout and inside a linear layout inside of another linearlayout?

Comment: I think it is better to favor the LinearLayout than the RelativeLayout, so the solution with less relatives layout. Also about the layouts you wrote I would start with a LinearLayout on the parent with vertical orientation, add the empty list text differently, and don't bother with the align bellow id's.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.maks.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|end"
        android:background="#ff4fc3f7" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/BusinessLogoCircleImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/BusinessNameTextView"
            android:typeface="normal" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/BusinessAddressTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessNameTextView"
            android:typeface="normal" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Website"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/BusinessWebsiteTextView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/BusinessAddressTextView"
            android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:text="5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CommentsCountTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="normal" />
    <TextView
        android:text="overall thanks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CommentsCountTextView"
        android:id="@+id/CommentsTextTextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:typeface="normal" />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CommentsTextTextView"
        android:id="@+id/StaffTeamListView" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyMessagesListTextView"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Use this. Hope help you.